# Rcpp sum over multiple indexes

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to compute a function of the form:

```
$m_{jl}(x) = x + \gamma[j]*zeta[j,l] + sum_{k \neq j} zeta[j,k]$
```

using `Rcpp`. My problem is about the `sum_{k \neq j} zeta[j,k]$`.. I would like to be able to do something `zeta[j,-j]`. Is it possible? I tried `zeta(j,-)-zeta(j,j)`, but the `Rcpp` does not like `zeta(j,-)`.

Comment: -1 for lack of research.

Comment: In addition, package authors are more likely to respond when you spell the package name correctly...

Answer (score 2):

You can use sugar functions:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double myFun(NumericMatrix x) {
   return sum(x)-sum(diag(x));
}
```

R:

```
A <- matrix(1:9,3)

sum(A)-sum(diag(A))
#[1] 26

myFun(A)
#[1] 26
```

I suspect this could be made faster with RcppEigen.